# Separating Axis Theorem issues

Tags: c#, xna, 2d, game-physics

I'm currently attempting to add an overlap tester for an axis aligned and orientated bounding box but the solution only seems to work accurately when the OBB's angle is between -10 and +10. As the angle approaches +90 degrees the collision area seems to at first move to the right half of the OBB and then become non existent. Between 90 and 270 I couldn't get an overlap and then when it comes round a full 360 the area registers accurately again.

Any light on this subject would be great. I'm using positive X for 0 degrees increasing CCW.

Cheers.

EDIT: Did a little more research and realised that projecting a vector onto another requires more than just a dot product. Could any one give me a correct version of one of the check axis methods below pretty pretty please :)

EDIT 2: Actually just a dot product should do I think since the vectors being projected onto are unit length.

```
public static bool overlapAABB_OBB(AABB a, OBB o)
    {
        float rads = MathHelper.ToRadians(-o.angle);
        T = Vector2.Subtract(o.position, a.position);
        Ax.X = 1;
        Ax.Y = 0;
        Ay.X = 0;
        Ay.Y = 1;
        Ox.X = (float)Math.Cos(rads);
        Ox.Y = (float)Math.Sin(rads);
        Oy.X = -Ox.Y;
        Oy.Y = Ox.X;
        if (checkAX(a, o) &&
           checkAY(a, o) &&
           checkOX(a, o) &&
           checkOY(a, o))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    private static bool checkAX(AABB a, OBB o)
    {
        float TAx = Vector2.Dot(T, Ax);
        float WoOxAx = Vector2.Dot(Vector2.Multiply(Ox, o.halfWidth), Ax);
        float HoOyAx = Vector2.Dot(Vector2.Multiply(Oy, o.halfHeight), Ax);
        if (TAx > a.halfWidth + WoOxAx + HoOyAx)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

    private static bool checkAY(AABB a, OBB o)
    {
        float TAy = Vector2.Dot(T, Ay);
        float WoOxAy = Vector2.Dot(Vector2.Multiply(Ox, o.halfWidth), Ay);
        float HoOyAy = Vector2.Dot(Vector2.Multiply(Oy, o.halfHeight), Ay);
        if (TAy > a.halfHeight + WoOxAy + HoOyAy)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

    private static bool checkOX(AABB a, OBB o)
    {
        float TOx = Vector2.Dot(T, Ox);
        float WaAxOx = Vector2.Dot(Vector2.Multiply(Ax, a.halfWidth), Ox);
        float HaAyOx = Vector2.Dot(Vector2.Multiply(Ay, a.halfHeight), Ox);
        if (TOx > o.halfHeight + WaAxOx + HaAyOx)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

    private static bool checkOY(AABB a, OBB o)
    {
        float TOy = Vector2.Dot(T, Oy);
        float WaAxOy = Vector2.Dot(Vector2.Multiply(Ax, a.halfWidth), Oy);
        float HaAyOy = Vector2.Dot(Vector2.Multiply(Ay, a.halfHeight), Oy);
        if (TOy > o.halfHeight + WaAxOy + HaAyOy)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I posted the question on GameDev.stackexchange and received this answer from rraallvv which has fixed the issue.

dot product is negative when the angle between the two vectors is greater than 90º, for the code to work properly you would need to take the absolute value of the dot product.

```
//...
private static bool checkAX(AABB a, OBB o)
{
    float TAx    = Math.Abs( Vector2.Dot(T, Ax) );
    float WoOxAx = Math.Abs( Vector2.Dot(Vector2.Multiply(Ox, o.halfWidth), Ax) );
    float HoOyAx = Math.Abs( Vector2.Dot(Vector2.Multiply(Oy, o.halfHeight), Ax) );
    if (TAx > a.halfWidth + WoOxAx + HoOyAx)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
//...
```

this also applies to `checkAY`, `checkOX`, and `checkOY`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the fix offered by Mazk1985, there is a typo in the checkOX() function.  o.halfHeight should be o.halfWidth, as seen below:

```
private static bool checkOX(AABB a, OBB o)
{
    float TOx = Vector2.Dot(T, Ox);
    float WaAxOx = Vector2.Dot(Vector2.Multiply(Ax, a.halfWidth), Ox);
    float HaAyOx = Vector2.Dot(Vector2.Multiply(Ay, a.halfHeight), Ox);
    if (TOx > o.halfWidth + WaAxOx + HaAyOx)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```